# re; using 2 i-phones simultaneously in adjoining rooms for video input to macbook pro

Tags: video, video-recording

I would like to 'overlay' two individual video feeds from two i-phones (with individual audio feeds from each person via XLR cable) to an existing video so as to stream both the prerecorded video as well as the live video simultaneously.

Meaning: I would first create a 'zoom-like' video with 2 'missing' squares.  When going live, I want to fill in the missing squares with the live video (and audio) from our i-phones.

Any suggestions?  Many thanks in advance!
Bill

Comment: You need a video switcher and real cameras, not iPhones.

Comment: OBS could function as a video switcher and I think it supports multiple iPhone video inputs. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you so much Matt!